# How to use GCD for lightweight transactional locking of resources?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to use GCD as a replacement for dozens of atomic properties. I remember at WWDC they were talking about that GCD could be used for efficient transactional locking mechanisms.

In my OpenGL ES runloop method I put all drawing code in a block executed by `dispatch_sync` on a custom created serial queue. The runloop is called by a CADisplayLink which is to my knowledge happening on the main thread.

There are ivars and properties which are used both for drawing but also for controlling what will be drawn. The problem is that there must be some locking in place to prevent concurrency problems, and a way of transactionally querying and modifying the state of the OpenGL ES scene from the main thread between two drawn frames.

I can modify a group of properties in a transactional way with GCD by executing a block on that serial queue.

But it seems I can't *read* values into the main thread, using GCD, while blocking the queue that executes the drawing code. `dispatch_synch` doesn't have a return value, but I want to get access to presentation values exactly *between* the drawing of two frames both for reading and writing.

Is it this `barrier` thing they were talking about? How does that work?

Comment: you might find that atomic properties work just as well and that you dont need to refactor your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the async writer / sync reader model was designed to accomplish.  Let's say you have an ivar (and for purpose of discussion let's assume that you've gone a wee bit further and encapsulated all your ivars into a single structure, just for simplicity's sake:

```
struct {
  int x, y;
  char *n;
  dispatch_queue_t _internalQueue;
} myIvars;
```

Let's further assume (for brevity) that you've initialized the ivars in a dispatch_once() and created the _internalQueue as a serial queue with dispatch_queue_create() earlier in the code.

Now, to write a value:

```
dispatch_async(myIvars._internalQueue, ^{ myIvars.x = 10; });
dispatch_async(myIvars._internalQueue, ^{ myIvars.n = "Hi there"; });
```

And to read one:

```
__block int val; __block char *v;
dispatch_sync(myIvars._internalQueue, ^{ val = myIvars.x; });
dispatch_sync(myIvars._internalQueue, ^{ v = myIvars.n; })
```

Using the internal queue makes sure everything is appropriately serialized and that writes can happen asynchronously but reads wait for all pending writes to complete before giving you back the value.   A lot of "GCD aware" data structures (or routines that have internal data structures) incorporate serial queues as implementation details for just this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

dispatch_sync allows you to specify a second argument as completion block where you can get the values from your serial queue and use them on your main thread.So it would look something like

```
dispatch_sync(serialQueue,^{
    //execute a block
    dispatch_async(get_dispatch_main_queue,^{

        //use your calculations here
    });
});
```

And serial queues handle the concurrency part themselves. So if another piece is trying to access  the same code at the same time it will be handled by the queue itself.Hope this was of little help.

Comment: I can't see the second argument in your code example. Is it supposed to be a dispatch_async *inside* the dispatch_sync block, or an argument to dispatch_sync? Also, if you call dispatch_async: after the initial dispatch_sync returns, the changes written back in the second block aren't there yet, since it's async. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: sorry about the second argument part...I meant the dispatch_async/dispatch_sync...And I didnt get "the changes written back in the second block aren't there yet, since it's async"? You run the dispatch_sync block which will make sure you have the values for the next async block.But as I said the second block is the completion block it can be async or sync...Usually I use async as it gives a better user experience or sync if the code resides in any of my initial routines.